# Graph with perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected graph which has a [perfect matching](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html). Devise (and prove its correctness) an $O(|V | + |E|)$ time complexity algorithm that constructs a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ such that $V (T)$ admits a bipartition in two stable sets of maximum cardinality in $T$.

I encountered this problem in a [book](https://www.elsevier.com/books/combinatorial-problems-and-exercises/lovasz/978-0-444-81504-0) I have about graphs theory, and I struggled for a couple of hours already. The problem is I do not have a starting point for it. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the title of the book in the question?

Comment: It is a book based on this book (written by a local author) "Lovasz L., Combinatorial Problems and Exercises, 2nd edition, North Holland, 1993"

Answer (score 0):

Modify BSF so that whenever a vertex is labeled as visited the matched vertex under the perfect matching is also labeled. The resulting tree will have the desired property.